# Rational Performance Tester, How to use value from generated on each test?

Tags: http, rational-performance-test

So I have a HTTP Test with rational performance tester

In the application, it has a form with hidden fields containing value which is automatically generated for each session..

How to use the value generated for each test being run rather than the recorded one? because the value is gibberish and hard to be defined by datapool thus I can't create data pool for the hidden field

Answer (score 1):

Rational Performance Tester has a couple of built-in data sources including a random number generator that you may use for substituting the hidden field value.

To use this, select the value that you have to substitute at playback, right-click and on the pop-up menu select "Substitute"->"Select Data Source".

Click on the Built-in data sources button and pick up "random" from the list of available built-in sources.
[Built-in Data Sources button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5FQU.jpg)

Depending on the format and length of the hidden value in your form, Random number may or may not work. If it doesn't you might have to generate a value using Java custom code. Refer the [RPT Knowledge Center article on custom code](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMMM5_8.6.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.common.doc/topics/textndteswcc.html) in that case.

Comment: Because I didn't about the number pattern (all I know is it is in sequential)

Will manually correlating data work with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> In the application, it has a form with hidden fields containing value which is >automatically generated for each session..
>
> How to use the value generated for each test being run rather than the recorded one?

Sorry if I am misinterpreting the question, but it sounds really like you're asking how to correlate data in RPT.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMMM5_8.6.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.common.doc/topics/cdatacorr.html?lang=en

Essentially, you are capturing a value that matches a certain pattern, for instance the value field of a hidden field with a certain id or nth match etc.

Saving this as a variable or straight up substituting the variable for the value you want to replace in the recorded test itself.

So for example you could take the value from the hidden field and use it as part of the form submission process.

Typically I turn off automatic data correlation and manually correlate where needed.